# Display Multiple Member Path for Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm binding the ItemsSource of my Listbox to list of Event class. 
Event has the following properties:

```
Date
Title
Company
Description
```

I can Currently Display any 1 of those properties using the line below:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredEventsCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Date"/>
```

I want to display all the information, May I ask how do I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make use of [Data Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) to Display various properties inside different controls inside listbox

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredEventsCollection}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Company}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Description}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```